# Unable to create user on Ubuntu Server with Ansible

Tags: server, groups

I run the following ansible script on my Centos and Ubuntu servers.

```
- name: add user testuser1
  user:
    name: "testuser1"
    state: present
    groups: "wheel"
```

The script worked fine on Centos but failed on Ubuntu.

The error message was:

```
fatal: [ubuntu1]: FAILED! => {
"changed": false, 
"failed": true, 
"invocation": {
"module_args": {
"append": false, 
"comment": null, 
"createhome": true, 
"expires": null, 
"force": false, 
"generate_ssh_key": null, 
"group": null, 
"groups": [
"wheel"
], 
"home": null, 
"login_class": null, 
"move_home": false, 
"name": "testuser1", 
"non_unique": false, 
"password": null, 
"remove": false, 
"seuser": null, 
"shell": null, 
"skeleton": null, 
"ssh_key_bits": 0, 
"ssh_key_comment": "ansible-generated on ubuntu1", 
"ssh_key_file": null, 
"ssh_key_passphrase": null, 
"ssh_key_type": "rsa", 
"state": "present", 
"system": false, 
"uid": null, 
"update_password": "always"
}
}, 
"msg": "Group wheel does not exist"
}
```

Does anyone have any idea why it failed on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think ubuntu has a group named wheel, you can use

```
addgroup wheel
```

however it may be best if you what it is you are trying to accomplish.
Are you trying to add to the sudoers group? as this group is sudoers

```
usermod -aG sudo testuser1
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `wheel` group in Ubuntu.  That's a Debian-ism that did not get included in Ubuntu by default.

The corresponding equivalent group for `sudo` access in Ubuntu is called `sudo`.  You should be adding users who get `sudo` access to that group, and not `wheel`.

Comment: I'm trying to create a new group called 'Wheel'..

Comment: I created a new group called 'Wheel' in both Centos OS and Ubuntu. The group was created in Centos but not in Ubuntu, and I don't know why?

Comment: Just to clarification the group name doesn't matter .. the group could have been called anything - the fact is that the group wasn't created in Ubuntu, but it was created in Centos.